# my unique true key is not working for phone number but working for email field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, crud

here I am giving my code why I am getting null for password but not for email

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: { type: String, default: '' },
    lastName: { type: String, default: '' },
    fullName: { type: String, default: '' },
    email: { type: String, unique: true, default: '' },
    password: { type: String, default: '' },
    address:{
        city:{
            type: String,
            default: null
        },
        street: {
            type: String,
            default: null,

        },
        houseNumber:{
            type: Number,
            default: null
        },
    },
    phoneNumber: { type: Number,  unique: true, required: true, index: true },
},{ timestamps: true });

    //add user function
    addUser: (req, res, next) => {
        try {
            // creating & adding user
            let user = new User();
            user.firstName = req.body.firstName;
            user.lastName = req.body.lastName;
            user.fullName = req.body.firstName + " " + req.body.lastName;
            user.email = req.body.email.toLowerCase();
            user.phoneNumber = req.body.phoneNumber;
            // save user
            
            user.save((err, data) =>{
                console.log(err);
                             
                if(err){
                    if(err.code == 11000) {
                     res.status(422).send('Duplicate email found');
                    }
                    else{
                    return next(err);
                    }
                }
                else{
                   return  res.send(data)
                }
            })
        } catch (error) {
            return res.send(error.message);
        }
    },
```

In the above code while in user.save function I am not getting error for password but for email.

I have checked some links bu unablet o find solution why is this happening

Comment: Can you please mention what exact error you are facing. Also, I noticed that you aren't saving the password while creating the user object.

Comment: Changes in mongoose schema may not be automatically propagated to the database, make sure those unique indexes exist in the db